# Number theory textbook with an algebraic perspective

Tags: soft-question, nt.number-theory, books

Most of the number theory textbooks I've dealt with take a very classical approach to the subject.  I'm looking for a textbook that's something like a first course in number theory for people who have a decent command of modern algebra (at the level of something like Lang's Algebra).  Does such a book exist, and if it does, what is it called?

Edit: As I posted in a comment below:

In the introduction to Ireland and Rosen, they note something that was bugging me for a while, "Nevertheless it is remarkable how a modicum of group and ring theory introduces unexpected order into the subject."

This is precisely the perspective I was looking for, so if anyone passes by this topic looking for a book that approaches number theory in this way, I feel like this quote should point him (her?) in the right direction.

Comment: fpqc--If you'd like to come by my office and take a look at some of these books, I have many of them on my shelf, feel free to send me an e-mail and stop by.


Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are probably many such books, for instance "[Fundamentals of Number Theory](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486689069.html)" by LeVeque, "[Elementary Number Theory](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486458075.html)" by Bolker and "[A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory](http://www.springer.com/math/numbers/book/978-0-387-97329-6)" by Ireland and Rosen.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation of one in particular?

Comment: I like all three; LeVeque is a good and cheap, though I'm not sure what level you aim at. 

Comment: I'm looking through Ireland and Rosen right now, and it seems to be what I was looking for.

Comment: I like Ireland-Rosen book very much too.

Comment: Seconded. I always wish to have read Ireland-Rosen much earlier.

Comment: Thirded for Ireland-Rosen.

Answer (score 6):

Well, it depends on the actual subject you want to approach and the "decent command of modern algebra" already assumed; without knowing more, I would recommend:

- *Number fields* (1995) by **Marcus**. Universitext. Just as the title says, a (great!) introduction to number fields.
- *Algebraic Number Theory* (1986) by **Cassels** and **Frölich**. Academic Press. It explains the basics (class field theory, zeta functions) to understand the Langlands Program.
- *A course on arithmetic* (1996) by **Serre**. Graduate Texts in Mathematics. P-adic fields, quadratic forms, zeta functions and modular forms.

Comment: I was looking not for a book on algebraic number theory, but an algebraic book on number theory, if you understand the distinction I'm trying to make.

Comment: Not really. Can you elaborate, please? Maybe I can suggest some other kind of books!

Comment: In the introduction to Ireland and Rosen, they note something that was bugging me for a while, "Nevertheless it is remarkable how a modicum of group and ring theory introduces unexpected order into the subject."  This is precisely the perspective I was looking for.

Comment: Serre is a very specific book; I wouldn't call it a first course at all.

Comment: Right; I somewhat managed to skip the "first course" part when reading the question :P

Comment: I wish Marcus's "Number fields" had a new edition, typeset, not typewritten. Otherwise, it's a great book with lots of hands-on material.

Comment: @lhf, the good news is that, after many years, there is a newly-typeset edition of Marcus: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-90233-3 (Springer 2018)

Answer (score 5):

Borevich-Shafarevich

Answer (score 3):

If I understand it well now, what you want are books about **basic** number theory with a good algebraic foundation. I can recommend the following:

- *Elementary methods in number theory* (2000), by **Nathanson**. Graduate Texts in Mathematics. It starts low, but it reaches quite high.
- *Elementary Number Theory with Applications* (2007) by **Koshy**. Elsevier. Truly basic. Not very very algebraic, but a really nice textbook.
- *Algebra and number theory* by Andrew **Baker**. Online notes. Fairly basic.
- *A computational introduction to number theory and algebra* (2005) by **Shoup**. Cambridge University Press / Online Free Version. Despite the title, I think it satisfies the conditions you are looking for.

Comment: Numbers one and three look interesting, while numbers two and four look awful.  